# Ios background timed requests

Tags: ios, background-task

I am implmenting ios app which needs to send GET requests every 10 second when in background state. please give me a hint how to implement this option.

Comment: Are you talking about http GET requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible on iOS. There is no guarantee that the operating system will grant you background time every 10 seconds to do something.

You should read about background modes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html